# How to center list items on my nav bar?

Tags: css

new here don't really know a lot about coding yet. Could someone tell me how I could center the list items without messing anything up, thanks.

```css
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 19px;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
```

Comment: You should add your HTML too, not only CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `ul.topnav li {float: left;}` to `ul.topnav li {display: inline-block;}` and add `text-align: center;` to `ul.topnav`. So the stylesheet would look like this:

```
ul.topnav {
  ...
  text-align: center;
}
ul.topnav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` in the `nav`:

```
.ul.topnav {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

But if you add the HTML, I could help you a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

My suggested approach would be to wrap your ul in a `<nav>` element and then treat the `<ul>` as a inline-block element. That would give you a nice range of browser compatibility.

You can see the demo on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/dtmp1nne/)

But it goes like this:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Test</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Test</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Test</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>  
</nav>
```

CSS (just the altered part):

```
.navbar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it , but if It helps...

```
ul.topnav {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        height:100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }
    ul.topnav li {float: left; width:auto; height:100%;}

    ul.topnav li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        line-height:100px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 19px;
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-right:10px;
    }
    ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

    ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
```